# How to subset a database considering values from another?

Tags: r, database, subset

I have two databases and I need to compile information from both.

Let's say the first one (Db1) is like this:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3  
P1      2000    Type1    
P1      2000    Type2
P1      2001    Type2
P2      2000    Type1
P2      2001    Type1
P3      2003    Type3
```

While the second one (Db2) is like (simmilar values except `Col3` only gets `type4` values):

```
Col1    Col2    Col3  
P1      2000    Type4    
P1      2000    Type4
P1      2001    Type4
P2      2000    Type4
P2      2001    Type4
P3      2003    Type4
```

I want to create new databases by `Type1`,`2` and `3`, but joining the `Type4` by `Col1` and `Col2`. 
First, I just need to subset Db1  by `Col3` to get either Type 1, 2 or 3.

Then I want to go to Db2 to obtain all rows with the same `Col1` and `Col2` values as, for instance, `Type1` in Db1. So I would want only `Type4` values for combinations of P1-2000, P2-2000 and P2-2001 (so, filtered by `Type1`); but how can I subset that?

Expected output (for Type1):

```
Col1    Col2    Col3  
P1      2000    Type1    
P2      2000    Type1
P2      2001    Type1
P1      2000    Type4    
P1      2000    Type4
P2      2000    Type4
P2      2001    Type4
```

Comment: Would be clearer if you showed expected output.

Comment: @snoram you're right; just changed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only the R

```
lines =
'Col1    Col2    Col3  
  P1      2000    Type1    
  P1      2000    Type2
  P1      2001    Type2
  P2      2000    Type1
  P2      2001    Type1
  P3      2003    Type3'

Db1 = read.table(textConnection(lines), header = T)


lines =
'Col1    Col2    Col3  
  P1      2000    Type4    
  P1      2000    Type4
  P1      2001    Type4
  P2      2000    Type4
  P2      2001    Type4
  P3      2003    Type4'

Db2 = read.table(textConnection(lines), header = T)


#Filtering data Db1
Db1_new = Db1[Db1$Col3=='Type1', ]

#Filtering data Db2
Db1_f = Db1_new[!duplicated(Db1_new[,-3]), ] 
Db2_new = data.frame(Col1=NULL, Col2=NULL,  Col3=NULL)

for (i in 1:nrow(Db1_f)) {
  aux = Db2[Db2$Col1 == Db1_f$Col1[i] & Db2$Col2 == Db1_f$Col2[i], ]
  Db2_new = rbind(Db2_new, aux)
}


#Db1 merge with Db2
rbind(Db1_new, Db2_new)

#   Col1 Col2  Col3
#1    P1 2000 Type1
#4    P2 2000 Type1
#5    P2 2001 Type1
#11   P1 2000 Type4
#2    P1 2000 Type4
#41   P2 2000 Type4
#51   P2 2001 Type4
```

Comment: thanks!! But is there a way for R to identify the values in Col1 and Col2 for the second subset, instead of having to provide them? Because the database I am working with has more rows and values in Col1 and Col2, and I would like to reduce errors that could arrive in this part of the analyses...

Comment: see if that's it

Comment: it does work with the example that I provided but it is not working with the original database... just to be clear, why exactly did you go through the steps in "#Filtering data Db2"?

Comment: Db1_f = Db1_new[!duplicated(Db1_new[,-3]), ]  ----> 
remove the last column and delete duplicate rows

Comment: Db2_new = data.frame(Col1=NULL, Col2=NULL,  Col3=NULL) ----> creates a new dataframe

Comment: for (i in 1:nrow(Db1_f)) {
  aux = Db2[Db2$Col1 == Db1_f$Col1[i] & Db2$Col2 == Db1_f$Col2[i], ]
  Db2_new = rbind(Db2_new, aux)
}  ----> checks the Col1 and Col2 lines of Db1_f, which are the same in Db2, and stack them in Db2_new

Comment: it does work now, thanks!! I was attributing wrong names to the columns and that was the mistake!